# Compile Lua C Module with another 'external' library

Tags: c, gcc, module, lua, shared-libraries

```
 gcc -fpic -c -o LuaLIB.o LuaLIB.c -lFOREIGNLIB -Wall
 gcc -O -shared -lFOREIGNLIB -fpic -o LuaLIB.so LuaLIB.o -lFOREIGNLIB
```

This gives me:

```
 lua5.3: error loading module 'LuaLIB' from file './LuaLIB.so':
 libFOREIGNLIB.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

How can I use/include another library while compiling a C-module for Lua?

Comment: It's possible that Lua only looks in the current directory for libraries. Try using rpath (runtime library search path, as opposed to only the current LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable): `-rpath=/path/to/libdir` on the linker command so that Lua looks there as well. ... unless Lua doesn't care about rpath, in which case you might need to place the foreign lib in the working directory.

Comment: If you have libFOREIGNLIB.a, use that in the second line. In any case, `-lFOREIGNLIB` in the first line is not needed.

Comment: Yes I have that .a file, but how? How do I have to include that in the second line?